# Sort "orders" in batch of 4, based on most common products ordered

Tags: php, arrays

I have this problem, which I don't know how to even start with. It's kind of a puzzle, which can be probably solved many ways, but I don't have idea for single solution.

I have `$num_of_oders % 4 == 0` orders a.k.a. there will always be 4,8,12,16,etc orders.
Each order can have x number of ordered products.

Here is an example code:

```
$orders = [];

$orders[0]['order_id'] = 1;
$orders[0]['products'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

$orders[1]['order_id'] = 2;
$orders[1]['products'] = [3,4,13,99,76,23,12,14,53];

$orders[2]['order_id'] = 3;
$orders[2]['products'] = [1,54,23,2,34,10,11,13,14,15];

$orders[3]['order_id'] = 4;
$orders[3]['products'] = [30,31,32,33,34,35];

$orders[4]['order_id'] = 5;
$orders[4]['products'] = [30,31,32,33,34,35];

$orders[5]['order_id'] = 6;
$orders[5]['products'] = [89,65,31,26,54,78,14,45,62,46,34,12];

$orders[6]['order_id'] = 7;
$orders[6]['products'] = [23,21,22,24,25,26,27,28,29];

$orders[7]['order_id'] = 8;
$orders[7]['products'] = [23,21,22,24,25,26,27,28,29];

$orders[8]['order_id'] = 9;
$orders[8]['products'] = [23,44,34,36,37,38,86,45,41,67];

$orders[9]['order_id'] = 10;
$orders[9]['products'] = [1,23,11,13,15,32,45,65,75,24];

$orders[10]['order_id'] = 11;
$orders[10]['products'] = [15,16,77,65,48,34,67,87,45,24,68,90];

$orders[11]['order_id'] = 12;
$orders[11]['products'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,76,43,87,65,99,27,54,64,24,67,21];

$orders[12]['order_id'] = 13;
$orders[12]['products'] = [23,13,14,65,43,59,54,34,32,57,86,24,12,43,75];

$orders[13]['order_id'] = 14;
$orders[13]['products'] = [1,13,2,6,5,3,7,45,23,87,33,65,46,65,12,54,43];

$orders[14]['order_id'] = 15;
$orders[14]['products'] = [23,13,14,65,43,51,54,34,32,57,86,24,12,43,75];

$orders[15]['order_id'] = 16;
$orders[15]['products'] = [1,2,56,4,5,6,7,11,34,54,3,12,17,42,20,64,45,53,27,35,23];

foreach($orders as $order) {
    // What to do here??

}
```

My problem:
I need to filter orders in the batch of 4, but each batch needs to have/contain orders, which have most common ordered products (product ids). Order can be only in one batch.

In current case this mean the end result will be array of 4 batches. Each batch will have 4 orders and those orders will have the most common/same product ids.

This way I will be able to display batch by batch of orders to user/worker and he will be able to pick products from warehouse faster, since program will automatically select/filter orders with most common products

Can you please help me out solve this problem.

If you need any additional information, please let me know and I will provide. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: @vivek_23 huu I don't know if I'm smart enough, to manually pick out orders which have the most common ordered products in batch by 4 :D  I would probably do that whole day. I think the logic should be to compare each order with other orders and some sort glue them which are the most in common... some sort of ranking orders by relevance to other order. don't know really...

Comment: So, most common 4 in first batch and then less common 4 in next batch and so on? Is it that way?

Comment: I don’t see what your so-called “Working php fiddle” is supposed to have to do with this.

Comment: If you can not manage to produce a proper example of what the output should be regarding your shown input data, then you at least need to describe what you want to achieve better and less ambiguous. _“I need to sort the orders in the batch of 4, but they have to be grouped by where orders have the most common products (product ids)”_ - it is _really_ unclear what that is actually supposed to mean. By “sort” you actually mean _divide into_ batches of 4? […]

Comment: […] What do you mean by “grouped by” then? Grouping by usually means that records get grouped together based on certain common characteristics - but that normally does _not_ include a limitation to a specific number of records.

Comment: Ah sorry for ambiguity, I will update my question

Comment: @vivek_23 kind of yes.. each batch should have the most common for 4 orders. But each order can be only in one batch.

Comment: @misorude is it more clear now or you see there could be even better explanation?

Comment: @Valor_ `But each order can be only in one batch.` This makes it confusing for me. What if we run out of products for future batches due to this constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

The original code only sorted based on common products between 2 orders, and then grouped the maximums together. However this could yield a situation where you had a batch of 4 orders where the two pairs have no products in common. This updated code finds batches of 4 with the most common products between all 4 of them instead:

```
foreach ($orders as $k1 => $o1) {
    // find number of products in common with other orders
    foreach ($orders as $k2 => $o2) {
        if ($k2 <= $k1) continue;
        foreach ($orders as $k3 => $o3) {
            if ($k3 <= $k2) continue;
            foreach ($orders as $k4 => $o4) {
                if ($k4 <= $k3) continue;
                $order_set = "{$o1['order_id']}-{$o2['order_id']}-{$o3['order_id']}-{$o4['order_id']}";
                $common[$order_set] = count(array_intersect($o1['products'], $o2['products'], $o3['products'], $o4['products']));
            }
        }
    }
}
arsort($common);
$orders_used = array();
foreach (array_keys($common) as $order_set) {
    list($o1, $o2, $o3, $o4) = explode('-', $order_set);
    // already output any of these orders?
    if (in_array($o1, $orders_used) || in_array($o2, $orders_used) || in_array($o3, $orders_used) || in_array($o4, $orders_used)) continue;
    $orders_used[] = $o1;
    $orders_used[] = $o2;
    $orders_used[] = $o3;
    $orders_used[] = $o4;
    // if we've used all the orders, quit
    if (count($orders_used) == count($orders)) break;
}
for ($i = 0; $i < count($orders_used); $i += 4) {
    $batch = array_slice($orders_used, $i, 4);
    echo "batch " . ($i / 4 + 1) . ": order ids " . implode(',', $batch);
    echo "; common products: " . $common[implode('-', $batch)] . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
batch 1: order ids 1,12,14,16; common products: 5
batch 2: order ids 3,6,13,15; common products: 3
batch 3: order ids 2,7,9,10; common products: 1
batch 4: order ids 4,5,8,11; common products: 0
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/2kd6B)

**Original answer**

Here's one way to do what (I think) you want. First, we compare each order with the others to determine how many products in common they have (using [`array_intersect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)). That list is then sorted in reverse order (i.e. greatest to least number of products in common) and we process it, adding each `order_id` to the `$orders_used` array as we find it in the array (but ignoring combinations where we've already output one of the orders). Once the entire array is processed all the orders will be in the `$orders_used` in reverse order of how many products they had in common with another order. This array can then be split into batches and output:

```
foreach ($orders as $key => $order) {
    // find number of products in common with other orders
    foreach ($orders as $k2 => $o2) {
        if ($k2 <= $key) continue;
        $common["{$order['order_id']}-{$o2['order_id']}"] = count(array_intersect($order['products'], $o2['products']));
    }
}
arsort($common);
$orders_used = array();
foreach (array_keys($common) as $order_pair) {
    list($order1, $order2) = explode('-', $order_pair);
    // already output these orders?
    if (in_array($order1, $orders_used) || in_array($order2, $orders_used)) continue;
    $orders_used[] = $order1;
    $orders_used[] = $order2;
    // if we've used all the orders, quit
    if (count($orders_used) == count($orders)) break;
}
for ($i = 0; $i < count($orders_used); $i += 4) {
    echo "batch " . ($i / 4 + 1) . ": orders " . implode(',', array_slice($orders_used, $i, 4)) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
batch 1: orders 13,15,14,16
batch 2: orders 7,8,4,5
batch 3: orders 1,12,3,10
batch 4: orders 9,11,2,6
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ibbFS)

Comment: Yes I think this is it. Let me run few tests so I will be sure, but looks nice ;)

Comment: @Valor_ I've updated my answer. The original could give you a batch with pairs of orders that had no common products. This new code looks for common products across all 4 orders so should better solve the problem.